# XSD multiple conditions

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I have an XML schema with the following piece of code:

```
<xs:attribute name="extension" use="required">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="((18)|(19)|(20))[0-9][0-9]((0[1-9]|1[0-2]))((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]))" />
    </xs:restriction>
    <xs:length value="8" />
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

This piece of code determines if a date of birth of people alive is correct or not. It is given that anybody is born in any year starting with 18, 19 or 20. Then followed by any two numbers, a month between 01-12 and a day between 01-31. The date of birth must contain 8 numbers to validate.

The question is if there is any way to develop this further? For instance if there is a year of birth 1809, it will validate even though it is impossible for someone in that age to be alive. Also a year in the future will validate - say 2058.

I there a way to put like "minyear" and "maxyear" where the first 4 numbers of the string cannot be less than $minyear or and greater than $maxyear?

I may also add that in direct connection with this 8 number string comes additional four numbers that are controlfigures and has nothing to do with years, month and day. That is why the base is string.

Any ideas?

/Paul

Answer (score 0):

Got this far:

```
<xs:attribute name="extension" use="required">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="(([1][8][9][0-9]|[1][9][0-9][0-9]|[2][0][0-1][0-9])(0[1-9]|1[0-2]))((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]))" />
    </xs:restriction>
    <xs:length value="8" />
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

This piece of code will restrict valid years from 1890 until 2019. The only problem is that the year 2019 will pass, besides that it works.

However it is not perfection and when the year 2020 comes it will let pass all years up to 2029, so is there a way to rule out that imperfection?

/Paul

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Solved:-)

The pattern section should be like this:

```
<xs:pattern value="(((189)[0-9]|(19)[0-9][0-9]|((200)[0-9]|(201)[0-8]))(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]))" />
```

This works in XML Schema 1.0. Perhaps there is a slicker solution in 1.1?

/Paul